# HELP WITH ASSIGNMENT. CENTER OF GRAVITY

Tags: statics

I have a Statics assignment which I don't seem to fully understand.

Here is the full assignment:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For the first question I have tried making several tables with Areas of each parts and the centre of gravity for each recognizable shape (triangle, square, circle, quarter circle, half circle). The problem is I don't understand how to piece it together. The figure doesn't have an xy axis (should it have one?).

I have made these calculations for the areas so far:

[image]

This is what I don't fully understand, how should one make use of this table. I have stumbled upon several tables which some contain the area A and coordinates x and y and others with only the area A and coordinate z. Which one to use? Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: I might not be seeing something, but what's the thickness of the green area? You seem to assume $2r$, but that's not given. It also seems to vary per section (the left vertical seems thicker than the right vertical), but the figure probably isn't to scale. Also, this is the worst assignment ever, good lord.

Comment: Duplicate of this - already on hold... https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/25343/10902